# Constant term of weakly modular form of weight 2 vanishes

Tags: fourier-series, modular-function

I stumbled upon this fascinating statement while browsing through old exercise sheets and don't find a fruitful approach to tackle the problem.

### Statement

The constant term of the Fourier expansion of a weakly holomorphic modular form of weight 2 (for the full modular group) vanishes.
I'm hoping for a hint helping me to understand that this is true.

### Description

In case a detailed description involving formulae is advantageous: Let $f: \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic mapping on the upper half plane, which fulfils

$$ f\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right) = (cz+d)^2 f(z)$$

for all $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix}\right) \in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. In this case, $f$ admits a Fourier expansion $f(z) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a(n) e^{2 \pi i n z}$, which is usually required to possess only finitely many negative terms, in which case it is called a *weakly holomorphic modular form* (of weight 2). 
The statement of concern asserts that $a(0)=0$ for such a function $f$.

Thanks for giving my request a thought!
Best, TFT

Comment: What is the dimension of the space of weight 2 modular forms?

Comment: @Somos: Thanks for your advice :)  
If I am not mistaken, your hint solves my problem:  
You may annihilate all negative terms of such a function by linear combination with derivatives of monomials of the j function -- an operation by which the constant term is unaffected. Then your hint comes into play.

Comment: Indeed -- this is why its derivative has weight 2, if I am not mistaken. If $f$ has weight $0$, then  
$f'(\gamma z) = \frac{\frac{d}{dz}(f(\gamma z))}{(\gamma z)'} = (cz+d)^2 \cdot f'(z)$, 
so that $f$ has weight $2$.

Comment: Is the space of weakly holomorphic modular forms of weight 2 closed under multiplication by the $j$ function?

Comment: I suppose, yes.
But I don't quite comprehend why this will help me ... and I don't understand why using your first hint, like I mentioned above, should be wrong :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Somos first comment, the question appears to be answered.

Let $j$ denote the Klein j function, then $(j^n)'$ is a weakly holomorphic modular form of weight $2$ for all natural numbers $n \in \mathbb{N}$, has leading term $q^{-n}$ (times a nonzero constant), where $q=e^{2 \pi i z}$, and its constant term vanishes.

So let $f$ be as above (the question), then an appropriate linear combination of $f$ and different $(j^n)'$ is a holomorphic modular form of weight $2$ (by annihilating negative powers of $q$). But this function has to be identically zero, by the valence theorem.

Since the above linear combination has the same constant term as $f$ has, the constant term of $f$'s Fourier expansion has to be zero.

Comment: @Somos: I suppose this is not a weakly holomorphic modular form of weight two. 
j is surjective, if I am not mistaken, so it should have a pole.