# Zero constant coefficient in weight 2 weakly holomorphic modular form

Tags: modular-forms

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2882894/constant-term-of-weakly-modular-form-of-weight-2-vanishes) seems to say that weight 2 weakly holomorphic modular forms have zero constant term. I don't quite follow the argument though... But I am wondering if this is also true for $M_{2}^{!}(N)$. That is, must $f \in M_{2}^{!}(N)$ have zero constant term in its Fourier expansion?

**Edit**: I am following an argument about a weight $2$, level $32$ weak form $f$. Let's say $f \in M^{!}_{2}(32)$ vanishes at all cusps except $\infty$. The meromorphic differential $f(z)dz$ is holomorphic everywhere except at $\infty$. The sum of residues of a meromorphic differential is $0$. Moreover, the residue at $\infty$ of any meromorphic differential $h(z)dz$, where $h$ is any weight $2$ form, is a multiple of its constant term in its $q$-expansion (why?). Thus the residue at $\infty$ must be $0$ (why?).

Comment: Wth is $M_2^\infty(8)$ ? The functions holomorphic on $H$ weight 2 invariant **for the full modular group** are of the form $P(j(z)) j'(z) = Q(j)'$ with $P$  a polynomial $ =Q'$ (the proof is that if $f$ is not of this form then for some polynomial $f-R(j)j'$ is in $M_2(SL_2(Z))$ thus it is $=0$). It is clear why the constant term at $i\infty$ vanish.

Comment: Do you know the correspondence between compact Riemann surface, affine curve, smooth model, meromorphic and holomorphic-one forms, the 2g closed loops generating the fundamental group ? The weight 2 modular forms are the holomorphic one-forms.

Comment: And Riemann-Roch. ${}{}$

Comment: @reuns I don't know any such correspondence. I don't know some of those words actually.

Comment: What you should investigate first : for a congruence subgroup $X=\Gamma\setminus \Bbb{H}$ is a compact Riemann surface, $F$ its field of meromorphic functions (meromorphic on $\Bbb{H}$, $\Gamma$ invariant, and $f\circ \gamma$ is meromorphic at $i\infty$ for all $\gamma\in SL_2(Z)$), then for all $f,g\in F, fdg$ is a meromorphic one-form : in local chart it is $f(z) g'(z)dz$ that except at the few poles we can integrate to produce a locally meromorphic function, to see if it integrates to a meromorphic function we check the few poles **and** if it integrates to $0$ on closed-loops.

Comment: Okay I can do that. But how will this help me answer my question?

Comment: The point is that (for $\Gamma$ a congruence subgroup) we can translate "the weight 2 $\Gamma$-invariant functions analytic on $\Bbb{H}$" as a Riemann-Roch problem, because if $h$ is in there then for some $h$ in the function field $f-h'$ is also in there with poles of order $\le 2g+2$ at the cusps (with $g$ the genus of the corresponding modular curve). The constant coef of $h'$ vanishes so it suffices to check the constant coefs of a basis of that Riemann-Roch space (a space of meromorphic one-forms). If we know the divisor of some meromorphic one-form we can turn it into a RR space $L(D)$.